# Stripe transaction charges

Tags: transactions, stripe-payments

Hello I am making an android application in which I am using Stripe payment method. Users can buy products through the app. I want User to only pay product price but not transaction charges. First I want to know that normally who pays the transaction charges the Buyer or the Seller ?

Comment: you likely want to talk to Stripe support: https://support.stripe.com/email

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Stripe charge(deduct fee) from the money you are asking to the buyer**

So, if you ask $10 from a user, then you will receive NET $9.41. $0.59 will be charged by Stripe.

If you want to pay Stripe fee from user then you have to calculate 2.9% of actual price + ¢30 to set the price. Example: for $10 product you have to ask $10.61 to buyer.

**You can check it in your test setup**

You have to find the **Balance** in **Payments** section in **Dashboard**. You can check NET amount seller received and total amount buyer paid.

Comment: Thank you boss :)

Comment: Welcome. No worries :)